# Function wp_enqueue_script allows duplicates

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I notice some plugins I use in WordPress are including the same css/js despite utilizing the wp_enqueue_script function.

I noticed a lot of plugins prefix the handle for common libraries with their plugin name for example "wpsm-bootstrap" and wonder if their choice of handle is the reason duplicates occur?

Example:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpsm_bootstrap', wpsm_dir.'assets/js/bootstrap.js', array(), '', true );
```

Should all plugins use the handle 'bootstrap' instead of prefixing the plugin name to the handle ('wpsm_bootstrap')?

I can't seem to think of any other reason for duplicates when using wp_enqueue_script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin developers might be using a partial implementation of bootstrap.js rather than loading the whole thing, or they might have hacked the version they used, or they might depend on a specific release.  There are legitimate reasons to do that so, to answer the question: No, plugins should not necessarily use the handle 'bootstrap'.